# BigNumber string error when passed as uint256

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I get the following error when passing `(new BigNumber('2')).exponentiatedBy(100)` big number value as uint256

```
Error: invalid BigNumber string value (arg="value", value="1.267650600228229401496703205376e+30", version=4.0.28)
```

I am using Truffle, but seems like a web3 issue? I'm not sure. Anyone seen this before. Wouldn't a valid uint256 go up to 2^255 ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what `BigNumber` version you have installed as part of your project.

But Truffle exposes a global `Web3` instance called `web3`, which exposes big-number functionality.

Therefore:

- If you're using Truffle v4.x, then you may as well do `web3.toBigNumber(2).pow(100)`.
- If you're using Truffle v5.x, then you may as well do `web3.utils.toBN(2).pow(100)`.

Comment: BN of web3 doesnt deal with decimals

Comment: Getting this error: ```An unexpected error occurred:

TypeError: num.bitLength is not a function
    at toBitArray (/home/pam/our-contracts/node_modules/number-to-bn/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:628:27)
    at BN.pow (/home/pam/our-contracts/node_modules/number-to-bn/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:1931:13)
    at test2 (/home/pam/our-contracts/tasks/2.js:16:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.```